# Look-up Or Replace Missing data in ETL extraction in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am extracting encounter data. using a stored procedure, from an EMR to load and format for a third party EDI vendor. Some of the data is missing a procedure code so I have created a "crosswalk" table that matches provider types and visit types to appropriate codes. Now I'm having trouble linking the table to where the code is supposed to be successfully.  What I need is essentially, "If the procedure code is null, go to this table and look for this provider type, then this visit type, and then use the procedure code associated with those two."

I tried using just a "Case when" loop but that produced a result so large that there wasn't enough storage for it to finish (which should definitely not be the case).  If I run just the code for the "lookup" table, making it a temp table, it produces the missing codes.  I just can't figure out how to insert that into the stored procedure.  Here's that code:

```
SELECT #Crosswalk.PROC_CODE
FROM #Crosswalk

SELECT 
DISTINCT 
       a.[encounter id],
       CASE
           WHEN a.[Code] IS NULL
           THEN CASE
                    WHEN a.[Provider] = b.[Provider]
                    THEN CASE
                             WHEN a.[Visit Type] = b.[Visit Type]
                             THEN b.[Proxy Code]
                             ELSE a.[Code]
                         END
                    ELSE a.[Code]
                END
           ELSE a.[Code]
       END AS 'PROC_CODE'
INTO #Crosswalk
FROM v_all_encounters AS a
     FULL OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Crosswalk] AS b ON a.[Provider] = b.[Provider]




/*  It needs to go in the stored procedure right where a.[Code] AS 'PROC CODE' is below; if a.[Code] is NULL--I need it to replace it with my alternate code*/

  '' AS 'Type_of_Service', 
  '' AS 'Revenue_Code',
  a.[Code] AS 'PROC_Code', 
  '' AS 'PROC_Code_MOD1',
```

Comment: Sample data might take longer to create than I have (it's medical information so I'd have anonymise all of it).  The desired results are a proprietary format that then gets turned into an 837.

Comment: If I have understood it right, then in the stored proc can you have one query for condition a.code is not null and other query with a.code is null. You can then union the queries. This way you are dealing with subset of data separately. Not sure if this will help without looking at sample data or sproc structure or desired output.